# Using aws cli, what is best way to determine the current region

Tags: amazon-web-services, region, aws-cli

Interactively, I can use "aws configure" to change or see the default region. Is there a "pwd" like function, documented or not that allows me to determine or confirm the current region mid-script ? Even if AWS_DEFAULT_REGION is not defined ? I want a script to run under a number of profiles. I can scrape from aws configure list, but is there something neater ?

Comment: is this script running on EC2?

Comment: No, Ubuntu outside from AWS.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The following gives the region actually used by the CLI regardless of whether environment variables are or are not set:

```
aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --output text --query 'AvailabilityZones[0].[RegionName]'
```

The region that will be used by the CLI is determined by the following order of precedence:

1. Command line `--region` option
2. Value of `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable
3. Region specified in the 'Current profile', which is determined by the following order of precedence

   - Command line `--profile` option
   - Value of `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable
   - Otherwise profile is [default]

Unfortunately using `aws configure get region` only returns the region as specified by your 'Current profile', and ignores the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable.

Rather than assuming any precedence rules, you can just use the CLI to make an actual API call and get the region from the result.  The only call I could find that should always work was to `aws ec2 describe-availability-zones`.  Another advantage of this method is that you can specify `--region` or `--profile` options and still get the right answer.

Comment: What does it mean if I call this with --region, and it just shows the value that was passed in on that switch?

Comment: @GaTechThomas You are right: it simply returns the region. I agree it’s trivial, but vaguely useful in the sense that the above command correctly interprets the same arguments that you intend to supply to the actual commands you want to run. This could be useful if your scripts are dynamically composing commands so you can’t anticipate exactly what arguments will be supplied.

Comment: Note that this does not work if your profile isn't authorized to execute the `DescribeAvailabilityZones` operation. You'll get an `UnauthorizedOperation` error.

Answer (score 125):

`aws configure get region` will get you the current region at that point in your script.

If you are using a profile, then type `aws configure get region --profile $PROFILE_NAME`.

Comment: This will return the region of the configuration, not the region that your aws cli invocation was performed from.  (e.g rm ~/.aws/config; aws configure get region  and notice it is empty (or remove your ENV vars or other locations of aws config settings).

Comment: 411
Unfortunately this does not always work. e.g. Say my profile is configured to eu-west-1, but I do: aws --region us-east-1 configure get region then this returns eu-west-1, even though using aws --region us-east-1 will operate upon the us-east-1 region.

Comment: correct. I don't know of any better way. Try the accepted answer

Comment: If you need to change the region of the current cli session: `aws configure set region us-east-1` (put the region you want).

Answer (score 43):

Perhaps, AWS has not provide to get the current region. However, instead of getting the current region, They provide to get a current availability zone via an instance metadata. All availability zones include a current region, so you can determine the current region with you replace a part of the current availability zone in a script on the EC2 instance.

For example:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/\(.*\)[a-z]/\1/'
```

Comment: Using AWS CLI, you could use `aws configure list | grep region` - this takes account of environment variables and `~/.aws/config`

Comment: As an aside, the curl example is good on the instance, I was looking for something for a bash include 'fragment' on a CLI client.

Comment: the above address returns nothing.  It really shouldn't be this hard to get the region as the AWS CLI is going to use it.

Comment: If using the metadata service anyhow, `/latest/meta-data/placement/region` has been added since NSR posted the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Taken from @RichVel's comment [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331788/using-aws-cli-what-is-best-way-to-determine-the-current-region#answer-31336629), to get the resolved region set from either `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` or the region in the aws config file (`aws configure get region` only gives the value set in the config file) use:

```
aws configure list | grep region | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Example:**

with `$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` unset:

```
$ echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

$ cat ~/.aws/config
[foo]
region = us-east-1
$ aws configure list | grep region | awk '{print $2}'
us-east-1
$ aws configure get region
us-east-1
```

with `$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` set:

```
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
$ echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
us-west-2
$ cat ~/.aws/config
[foo]
region = us-east-1
$ aws configure list | grep region | awk '{print $2}'
us-west-2
$ aws configure get region
us-east-1
```

Answer (score 12):

`aws configure get region` is neat but I wanted to be able to know the region even when `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` *was* set. Unfortunately, according to the documentation:

> Note that aws configure get only looks at values in the AWS configuration file. It does not resolve configuration variables specified anywhere else, including environment variables, command line arguments, etc.

Instead, assuming you have Python and boto3 installed, you can run:

```
python -c 'import boto3; print(boto3.Session().region_name)'
```

E.g.

```
$ AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 python -c 'import boto3; print(boto3.Session().region_name)'
us-east-1
```

Answer (score 12):

The region is in the following:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

So...

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|jq -r .region
```

Comment: Not from inside a CLI script on a client machine. This works on the instance. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure your intent for confirming the current Region setting, but why not just set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION in your script and force it to be what you want it?  You can then confirm it is set.

Answer (score 6):

This grows upon the answers by [Jeshan Babooa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41977894/) and [Alastair McCormack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54342092/832230) which have these known limitations:

- `aws configure get region` doesn't return the region if the region is defined by the environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.
- `boto3` may not always be available, even though `python -c 'import boto3; print(boto3.Session().region_name)'` works when it is available.

To address the above limitations, consider in Bash:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION:-$(aws configure get region)}
```

This uses the value of the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` if available, otherwise it uses the output of `aws configure get region`.

Comment: This seems a good enough answer that covers most "good faith" setup. Not sure whether it is absolutely foolproof because things like `.aws/config` profile setup for MFA, `AWS SSO`, or env vars `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, etc., may potentially derail the logic. I haven't tested, but it's too mind-boggling to be certain that we've covered all scenarios. In the end, the only foolproof method is the Python `boto3` test (which of course has its own baggage.)

Answer (score 5):

The region can be obtained using:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region
```

Comment: Yeah, that sounds obvious, but that tells you the region of the "client".  The client may be a laptop. This does not work on a laptop.  The original question's intent was to test for the region a given scripted command would be applied in.  This is easier nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

If you have region info for your profiles in `.aws/config`, you can do as follows:

Example of `.aws/config` (**note that `dev` profile is called `profile dev`**). The `profile` word is [imporant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/get.html).

```
[default]
region = ap-southeast-2

[profile dev] 
region = us-east-1
```

Then using cli, you can:

```
aws configure get profile.default.region
```

which gives `ap-southeast-2` and

```
aws configure get profile.dev.region
```

which gives `us-east-1`.

Comment: Possibly, but this is a bit rigid.  I could also store the current region in an environment variable if I was careful to maintain it rigorously. My needs were more along the lines of "region shopping" for an instance where availability ebbs and flows.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for you but I came to this page looking for similar advice. I am often switching between AWS Profiles which are configured to use different regions. In my case, the profile I am using is controlled by an environment variable - `AWS_PROFILE`

To get the current region, regardless of which profile I am using, I found this command useful:

```sh
aws configure get region --profile=$AWS_PROFILE
```

Answer (score -2):

Just execute
`vi ~/.aws/config`
to see your config file.

Comment: This works if you pick one and stay with it. The config file generally has the default, and it may not be the same for all profiles. I may use the same snippet after  the profile has been changed in the including script.  This was some time ago now, when capacity was more of an unknown, it still applies if you can't get the quota uplift or are logging this to a fixed location for audit or restart purposes.